# Very simple MySQL index query running very slowly

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing

I have a very simple query that is running extremely slowly despite being indexed.

My table is as follows:

```
mysql> show create table mytable
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `start_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ix_status_user_id_start_time` (`status`,`user_id`,`start_time`),
  ### other columns and indices, not relevant
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=115884841 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Then the following query takes **more than 10 seconds to run**:

```
select id from mytable USE INDEX (ix_status_user_id_start_time) where status = 'running';
```

There are about 7 million rows in the table, and approximately 200 of rows have status `running`.

I would expect this query to take less than a tenth of a second. It should find the first row in the index with status `running`. And then scan the next 200 rows until it finds the first non-`running` row. It should not need to look outside the index.

When I explain the query I get a very strange result:

```
mysql> explain select id from mytable USE INDEX (ix_status_user_id_start_time) where status = 
'running';
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+-------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type | possible_keys                | key                          | key_len | ref   | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+-------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable | NULL       | ref  | ix_status_user_id_start_time | ix_status_user_id_start_time | 195     | const | 2118793 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+-------+---------+----------+-------------+
```

It is estimating a scan of more than 2 million rows! Also, the cardinality of the `status` index does not seem correct. There are only about 5 or 6 different statuses, not 344.

## Other info

1. There are somewhat frequent insertions and updates to this table. About 2 rows inserted per second, and 10 statuses updated per second. I don't know how much impact this has, but I would not expect it to be 30 seconds worth.
2. If I query by both `status` and `user_id`, sometimes it is fast (sub 0.1s) and sometimes it is slow (> 1s), depending on the `user_id`. This does not seem to depend on the size of the result set (some users with 20 rows are quick, others with 4 are slow)

Can anybody explain what is going on here and how it can be fixed?

I am using mysql version 5.7.33

Comment: Why don’t you use an index on the status column alone? If the index is on 3 columns it will not help you if you just search for status only

Comment: `show create table tablename` is much more readable (and complete) than describe + show indexes

Comment: consider changing your status to an integer or enum?

Comment: Looks like index is not used as index but as compact table's copy. I.e. server fullscans the index. Test does `CREATE INDEX ix_status ON mytable (status)` improves. Test does `SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE status BETWEEN 'running' AND 'running'` is fast.

Comment: Do `ANALYZE TABLE` to see if it helps.

Comment: `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`  and turn on the Optimizer trace.

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff the first part of the index is on status, so it should still be useful.

Comment: @ysth I updated the question to use `show create table`

Comment: @Akina using `between` makes no difference. I don't see why it would.

Comment: @RickJames `analyze table` returns ok. What am I expecting to see or not see in the optimizer trace? Nothing jumps out at me as being interesting.

Comment: note that each index entry is 206 bytes, the vast majority of that being the status; if you truly have only only 5 or 6 statuses, using an integer or at least a smaller varbinary type will make a dramatic difference in how many index rows fit on a page and should speed up your query; but I don't think that would fully explain your 10 second time unless you are extremely IO bound

Comment: @ysth I am almost certainly not io bound. Running on nvme disks and < 1mb/s write < 0.2mb/s read happening on the disks in total.

Comment: Are there any other processes running, possibly holding locks on those rows?

Comment: @ysth - The index entry won't take 206 bytes -- only as much as need, probably 10-20 bytes.  And if there are only 200 results, then all of them will fit in a couple of blocks.  But, yes, a `TINYINT UNSIGNED` or an `ENUM` would shrink it down to 1 byte.  Still, it won't have much impact on the question at hand.

Comment: As you do not say how many indexes are on the table, and you have 7 mid row in the table, maybe you index buffer in the mysql config file is too low so the index is read from disk?

Comment: Since you mention that status cardinality is wrong, invalid table statistics can cause the query optimizer to do a full table scan, despite the index hint. Try 'FORCE INDEX' instead of 'USE INDEX'.

Comment: @MatBailie There are other updates touching those rows (specifically, updating the status), but I believe those should be relatively quick. There are about 10 indexes on the table, but I believe all the indexes fit in memory. There is lots of memory available on the machine and there is very little reading of disk. FORCE INDEX does not make a difference.

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff ^

Comment: @TonPlooij see my response above ^

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff your comment inspired me to look closer at this. Changing the global variable innodb_buffer_pool_size from 128MB to 12.8GB solved the problem. If you want to add an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: To be clear, it did not fully solve it. It now takes about 3 seconds to run instead of 10-30 previously. I still expect this query to run in < 1 second, but this is probably good enough for now.

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff - There is no separate "index buffer" in InnoDB -- all blocks (data or index) are cached in the "buffer_pool".  In this query, with 200 results, I would expect about 2 blocks (16KB each) to be needed.  So, it should be much less than 1 second, regardless of buffer_pool_size or how cold the cache is.

Comment: @Akina - MySQL optmiizer `x=1` better than `x>='...' AND x<='...'`.  At best, it might notices that the latter can be changed to the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comment, you are using many indexes on a big table. So the required memory for this indexes is very high.
You can increase the index buffer size in the my.cnf by changing the innodb_buffer_pool_size to a higher value.
But probably it is more efficient to use less indexes and do not use combined indexes if not absolutely needed.
My guess is, that if you remove all indexes and create only one on status this query will run in under 1s.

Comment: Caution:  Increasing the buffer_pool too much could lead to swapping, which would hurt performance tremendously.